# Problem executing a batch file in Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to execute a batch file in my Java application. The code is the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start C:/Documents and Settings/Zatko/My Documents/Project-Workspace/IUG/external/apps/archive/run-server.bat");
```

When it executes, a error dialog appear telling "Windows cannot find 'C:/Documents'. make sure you typed the name corretly...."

When I execute with the same code another batch file, named file.bat and located in the C:/Temp folder, it works perfectly....

Does anyone know where the problem may be? Is it about spacing characters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

It seems the start command needs an extra parameter whenever the path to the executable to start is enclosed in ". As one must surround parameters which contains spaces by " this is a little bit confusing as the start comand works as excepted when one has a path without spaces and thus does not enclose it with ". That's what happened when I tested the code below for a folder c:/temp and it worked without an additional parameter.

The parameter in charge is a title for the window that is opened. It must come es second paramter and if it contains spaces must be surrounded by ".

I suggest to always use " for both title and path.

So here is the updated command:

You need to enclose

> c:/Document and Settings/...

with " as the filename contains spaces. And you need to include a title when using the start command with a paramter with ".

For Java that would be:

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C
>   start \"Server\" \"C:/Documents and
>   Settings/Zatko/My
>   Documents/Project-Workspace/IUG/external/apps/archive/run-server.bat\"");

Greetz,
GHad

Comment: I did follow the instruction. However when I go to run the code, the DOS command window appears with the cursor flashing at 
C:\Documents and Settings\Zatko\My Documents\Project-Workspace\IUG\>

Comment: Check if your server has been started already. May the batch file starts a process which leaves the command window open. When I try with a batch containing only the pause command, it works perfectly here.

Comment: Do you need to change the / to \ as well?

Comment: It seems that the problem is indeed in the path: any batch file if located in the main C:/ folder is executed without problem. However if the same file is located in the C:/Documents and Settings/Zatko/My Documents/Project-Workspace/IUG/external/apps/archive/ simply doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

It's much better to use an array:

```
String[] array = { ... };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(array);
```

as in

```
String[] array = { "cmd", "/C", "start", 
    "C:/Documents and Settings/Zatko/My Documents/.../run-server.bat" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(array);
```

Using an array is specially important if you have spaces in one of the parameters, like you do.

Comment: can u give an example of using it in the above situation?

Comment: I certainly thought the same thing and tried it, but it doesn't work! It only opens up a command window with current folder as the project root (same as mentioned in tony's comment above)

Comment: I got the reason, check out my answer below

Answer (score 2):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start \"\" \"C:/Documents and Settings/Zatko/My Documents/Project-Workspace/IUG/external/apps/archive/run-server.bat\"");
```

should work.

You need to quote arguments with spaces or shell metacharacters in them. And `start` expects the first quoted argument to be a window title, so give it an empty one so it's happy.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

`List<String> templst = new ArrayList<String>();`

`templst.add("cmd");`

`templst.add("/C");`

`templst.add("start");`

`templst.add("backup.bat");`

`Process p = rt.exec(templst.toArray(new String[]{}), null, new File(path));`

Comment: don't try to use /b flag, it doesn't work in that case. Instead simply write exit as the last command in your batch file.